# Как поделиться ссылкой в мессенджере через браузер?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть кнопка по которой нужно открывать мессенджер (например телеграм), и отправлять туда ссылку, знаю про существование `navigator.share()`, но он открывает шторку со всеми приложениями, где можно поделиться, а нужно без нее. Подскажите где прочитать про это, сколько гуглил ничего полезного не нашел.

Comment: https://vk-book.ru/knopki-repostov-v-socialnye-seti-s-pomoshhyu-javascript/

Comment: спасибо, я тоже уже нашел способ через ссылки, а есть более нативное решение? В телеграмм например нельзя отправить сообщение через ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ВКонтакте: [https://vk.com/share.php?url=адрес_страницы](https://vk.com/share.php?url=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)
- Facebook:
  [https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=адрес_страницы](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)
- Одноклассники: [https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=адрес_страницы](https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)
- Twitter: [https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=адрес_страницы](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)
- Google plus: [https://plus.google.com/share?url=адрес_страницы](https://plus.google.com/share?url=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

а браузер сам уже предложит открыть приложение или откроет, если уже было разрешение

Comment: а есть более нативный способ, например для телеграмм? В него нельзя отправить сообщение через ссылку

Comment: @Sergey можно https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share

Comment: спасибо, увидел

Comment: последний вопрос - есть такая ссылка для инстаграмма? Час уже гуглю и ничего(

Comment: @Sergey  тоже прошерстила инет и пришла к выводу, что инстаграм не позволяет это делать. Например тут задавались таким вопросом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392424/how-can-i-create-an-instagram-sharer-link-in-php